# Akka Scheduler throws exceptions only in MicroKernel but works fine in eclipse IDE for scala

Tags: scala, akka, microkernel

I have a scheduler that looks like given below.  It is meant to send a message every 30 minute to another actor in the Actor system. This code works fine when I run it in eclipse IDE for scala.
However when I throw this code(with the bootable so that Microkernel can invoke it) in MicroKernel, I get an exception saying

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystem.dispatcher()Lscala/concurrent/ExecutionContext;
The full stack trace is given below.
I suspect the problem might be related to "import system.dispatcher" line that is not valid in this context. Or the Scheduler is trying to fire the message too soon.

Please help...

**scheduler.scala:**

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.actor._
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

class Scheduler extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    import transactions._

    val system = ActorSystem("Daemon")
    import system.dispatcher
    log.info("Scheduler initializing.")
    system.scheduler.schedule( 30 milliseconds, (1000*60*30 ) milliseconds){ 
                self! updateUows(new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()))}

    def receive = {

    case updateUows(time) => { 
        log.info("updateuow to be sent.")
        context.parent!updateUows(time) 
    }
    }

}
```

**The full stacktrace:**

```
    [DEBUG] [07/26/2013 15:38:23.324] [Daemon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [EventStream(akka://Daemon)] Default Loggers started
Uncaught error from thread [Daemon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[Daemon[ERROR] [07/26/2013
15:38:23.960] [Daemon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [ActorSystem(Daemon)] Uncaught error from thread [Daemon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] shutting down JVM since 'akka
.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystem.dispatcher()Lscala/concurrent/ExecutionContext;
        at org.exactearth.PVDaemon.Scheduler$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Scheduler.scala:25)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:506)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
]

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystem.dispatcher()Lscala/concurrent/ExecutionContext;
        at org.exactearth.PVDaemon.Scheduler$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Scheduler.scala:25)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:506)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Shutting down Akka...
Shutting down .............(my program)
```

Comment: What do you mean under it works fine in Eclipse? And where do you have a Kernel?

Comment: Is your class path the same for both you IDE and what's running under the micro kernel?  It seems as if maybe your micro kernel app might be picking up a different version of akka maybe.

Comment: Actually your problem was that you were trying to run with an Akka 2.1 microkernel while having compiled with Akka 2.2 (the two are not binary compatible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should create Actors with ActorSystem like in the code below:

```
case object StartSched

class Test extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = {
    case StartSched =>
      context.system.scheduler.schedule( 30 milliseconds, (1000*60*30) milliseconds){
        self ! updateUows(new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()))
      }
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sys = ActorSystem("Test")
    sys.actorOf(Props[Test])
  }
}
```

To start it in MicroKernel you should extend `Bootable` trait and overload two methods: `startup` and `shutdown`. [Docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/microkernel.html)

And creating ActorSystem inside an Actor **is a very bad decision.**

Comment: With out having the line import system.dispatcher the line context.system.scheduler.schedule gives compile time error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Alex. With out having the line "import system.dispatcher" the line context.system.scheduler.schedule gives compile time error. The error is  Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext. I forgot to mention that while running in Eclipse, I run the app as an object that extends App. Mine is a maven build which I convert to run in eclipse. I followed the http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/scheduler.html link for scheduler which looks similar to what you suggested.Am I recreating or grabbing the same actor system when I type ActorSystem("Daemon")?  new to scala:)

Comment: `And creating ActorSystem inside an Actor is a very bad decision.` -- why?

Comment: @user2624105 add `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`. No, by writing `ActorSystem("Daemon")` you'll create entirely new system

Answer (score 1):

The problem my code had was that it was trying to create the ActorSystem.

and import system.dispatcher is why the code failed.

Instead the line import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global gives the default executionContext to use.

Thanks Alex for guiding in me in the right direction.

```
case object StartSched

class Scheduler extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    import transactions._
    log.info("Scheduler initializing.")
    self!StartSched
    def receive = {
    case StartSched =>{
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    context.system.scheduler.schedule( 30 milliseconds, (1000*60*30) milliseconds){
        self ! updateUows(new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()))
      }
    }
    case updateUows(time) => { 
        log.info("updateuow to be sent.")
        context.parent!updateUows(time) 
    }
    case _=>{log.info("Don't know why we reached here.")}

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Roland's answer in the comments is the correct one. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Scala usually means that you use binary incompatible libraries.

You either use different major Scala versions in your IDE project and in your Microkernel app, or different major Akka versions.