# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: scala, akka

I have a main object in akka.

```
object Application extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  //...............
}
```

When I run it, it throws an exception of

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystem.dispatcher()Lscala/concurrent/ExecutionContext;`

How do I get rid of it?

I'm using **akka 2.2.0**

Comment: I think it's a problem with Akka 2.1. Are you on 2.1 or 2.2?

Comment: @HarshalPandya, that's 2.2.0

Comment: may be duplicated with [this][1], hope it helps


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890223/akka-scheduler-throws-exceptions-only-in-microkernel-but-works-fine-in-eclipse-i

Comment: Which version of scala are you using? Akka 2.2.0 should be run with scala 2.10.+. If you somehow are trying to run it with scala 2.9 (by example) you are bound to have those kinds of errors as `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` was only added in scala 2.10.0.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles, scala 2.10

Comment: My bad, looking again at the error it is obvious that the problem is not with the scala version, but rather with the fact that some part of your code (or dependency) expects akka version 2.2.0 (where `ActorSystem.dispatcher` returns an `ExecutionContext`) but you have actually loaded an earlier version (this method used to return a `MessageDispatcher`). There is a high chance that you have two different versions of akka in your classpath. By example some of your dependencies might load akka 2.1.4, while your code links again akka 2.2.0. Check all your transitive dependencies.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles, I'm using akka 2.2.0

Comment: I understand that. The question is: what other dependencies does your application have? Chances are that one of them has a dependency to another version of akka, and thus you are getting this other version (transitively) in your classpath.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles, do you mean build.sbt? I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have updated your answer with your "build.sbt" file, it is rather clear what is happening: your application has `"org.scalaj" % "scalaj-http_2.9.2" % "0.3.7"` as a dependency.
You are forcing the scala version for "scalaj", meaning that you will (transitively) get scala 2.9.2 pulled in your classpath, in addition to scala 2.10.2.
To avoid this, do **not** force the scala version in your dependencies, but let sbt infer it from your project's scala version, by using the `%%` operator instead of `%` (just like you did for your other dependencies):

```
"org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "0.3.9"
```

Note that I have upgraded the library version to 0.3.9 as it is apparently the first version to be available for scala 2.10.

Comment: I can't compile it due to the error of `(*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: junit#junit;4.10!junit.src`